# CakePHP - Pagination Query append default condition "TableName.deleted" != 1"

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I'm using Cakephp V2.0 and having huge application working on it. Below is the issue I'm facing.

Select Query is what automatically set condition like `"TableName.deleted" != 1`

Which does the creating issue actually, I want to add my custom condition in this query to get all soft-deleted records i.e.: **"TableName.deleted" == 1**.

But when we are using `$this->paginate()` function, it will append default condition at the end of MySQL query condition and then MySQL query will look like this:

```
("TableName.deleted" == 1) AND "TableName.deleted" != 1 Order By xyz
```

So it's retrieving the record set only by taking last condition and return only records which are not deleted.

How do I remove this default CakePHP condition (**"TableName.deleted" != 1**)?

**Edited (added code):**

```
if (isset($this->passedArgs['showdeleted']) && $this->passedArgs['showdeleted'] == 1) {
            $displayConditions['AND']['tableName.deleted'] = "1";
        } else {
            $displayConditions['AND']['tableName.deleted'] = "0";
        }

        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $displayConditions,
            'fields' => $this->displayFields,
            'limit' => $show_page,
            'group' => 'tableName.id',
            'contain' => array(
                'tbl1',
                'tbl2',
                'tbl3',
                'tbl4',
                'tbl5',
            ),
        );

        $returnRecords = $this->paginate();
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Could you add some code to your question so that we can see how you're building your query? :-)

Comment: `How do i remove this default CakePHP condition` - That is not a default CakePHP condition. You need to show what you're doing.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja & AD7six : I have added sample code in my above question. please check. i have added one condition related to this deleted field and it works how i explain above in my question.

Comment: Nothing in the question is responsible for `"TableName.deleted" != 1`. I would start by looking at what behaviors you are using and then (how surprising) removing/disabling the soft delete behavior which you're probably using if you want to show deleted records.

Comment: @AD7six: thats what my question is. :)

Comment: It is not the role of SO readers to guess where you've put/added code that does something that _does not happen automatically with the tools you are using_. Please do some debugging/work, or simply think about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggesting and comments.

Actually i got the answer for the same. we have created behavior for the same

**SoftDeletableBehavior.php**

In which we have defined related methods which was appending the condition **"TableName.deleted" != 1**. and it was also mentioned in Model as well like below:

```
var $actsAs = array(
        'SoftDeletable' => array(
            'field' => 'deleted',
            'find' => true
        ),

    );
```

so i just made one very minor change and it's working.

```
var $actsAs = array(
            'SoftDeletable' => array(
                'field' => 'deleted',
                'find' => false
            ),

        );
```